# Different ways of declaring a function in Python

Tags: python, function, lambda, declaration

I know two ways to declare a function (Examples below). Are there other ways?

```
#example 1
def f(x): return x

#example 2
f = lambda x: x
```

Comment: I think that's it.

Comment: Note that lambdas are very limited. They can only have one expression, and no control flow other than the conditional operator, no local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function directly given a code object and a global namespace. This is *not* something you would ever use in almost any real code.

Here is a bare-bones example:

```
>>> import types
>>> code_obj = compile('print("hello world")', '', 'single')
>>> g = {'print': print}
>>> f = types.FunctionType(code_obj, g)
>>> f()
hello world
```